# Let a client log in to the site when the system is off

Tags: login

I would like to let a client log in to the site when the system is off, but without CP access. I have created a user group named «testing-group» with one checkbox checked: «Access the site when the system is off», and I have assigned a user to this group. I have created a 503.html template in the templates folder, and the login form provided in the docs,  http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/login-form, is in this template. The form is displayed, but nothing happens when I try to log in (happens both with admin account and the user assigned to the group «testing-group» ).

Comment: Per Brad's answer, this was due to a bug. Closing this as a "bug report".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a bug in Craft that prevented a scenario like the one you're trying to achieve from happening.

It has been fixed for the next (post [2.4.2702](http://buildwithcraft.com/updates#build2702)) release, though!